# dxGDIPlusClasses.pas not found error delphi 10

Tags: delphi

When I tried to compile one of my BPL files, I get an error:

> dxGDIPlusClasses.pas not found.

I double checked the unit file exists on the hard drive.

I also added `$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Dcp` to the DCP Output directory, and `$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Bpl` to the Package Output directory. The runtime package containing the unit was also added to the BPL.

I searched online for answers, foound one suggestion to enable `Build with runtime packages` under the Project Options, but when I checked I dont have that option.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Which .Bpl files are you trying to compile, the Devex ones or your own?

Comment: Every version of Delphi has the `Build with runtime packages` option.

Comment: The runtime package containing the unit was added where? It should be added to the references (`requires` clause in the `.dpk`). But if that package was not compiled with Delphi 10 Seattle too, it won't work. The `.dcu` must have been compiled with DX Seattle as well.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that either:

1. the compiler can't find the source file it needs for the unit.
2. the compiler found a `.dcu` file compiled with a different version of the compiler and needs to recompile it.

`.dcu` files are not compatible across compiler versions (with the single exception of D2006->D2007), meaning that every new version release of the compiler means all your source needs to be recompiled in order to be compatible with it.

You need to add the path to the source to `Project->Options->Directories and Conditionals->Search Path` so it can find the source code it needs.

Comment: I believe you mean D2006->D2007.  That was definitely not the case for D6->D7.

Comment: @JonRobertson: Yes, I did. Remy beat me to the fix, but thanks for pointing it out. :-)